# Linq To Sql Problem

Tags: linq-to-sql

**it will give me error Unable to cast object of type**.

```
  public class CusInfomration
   {
      public string CustomerName { get; set; }
      public string CustomerID { get; set; }
      public string OrderDate { get; set; }
      public string OrderId { get; set; }
   }

  var CustomerFromWash =  from p in _NorthWindDataContext.Customers
                          join q in _NorthWindDataContext.Orders 
                          on p.CustomerID   equals q.CustomerID
                          where p.Region == "WA"
                          select new
                         {                                                   
                             CustomerName =Convert.ToString(p.CompanyName),
                             CustomerID = Convert.ToString(p.CustomerID),
                             OrderId = Convert.ToString(q.OrderID),
                             OrderDate = Convert.ToString(q.OrderDate),
                          };

  List<cusinfomration> lstCust = (List<cusinfomration>)CustomerFromWash;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That LINQ query returns an `IQueryable<T>`.  `IQueryable<T>` is an interface and `List<T>` does not implement it, so there is no way that the underlying, concrete implementation is a `List<T>` (it does however implement `IEnumerable<T>`, so a cast to that would be valid).  Even if it were it would not be a safe cast to make as the .NET folks may want to change out the underlying implementation someday and your cast would be broken.  Not a good idea even if it did work initially.

You can call `ToList()` on the return value of the LINQ query:

```
var CustomerFromWash = (from p in _NorthWindDataContext.Customers
                        join q in _NorthWindDataContext.Orders 
                        on p.CustomerID   equals q.CustomerID
                        where p.Region == "WA"
                        select new
                        {                                                   
                           CustomerName =Convert.ToString(p.CompanyName),
                           CustomerID = Convert.ToString(p.CustomerID),
                           OrderId = Convert.ToString(q.OrderID),
                           OrderDate = Convert.ToString(q.OrderDate),
                        }).ToList();
```

Even then though you are selecting a collection of anonymous types, not `CustInformation` objects.  If you want `CustInformation` objects to be returned then you will need to:

```
select new CustInformation 
{
    // set properties here
}
```